# "parking around back" for signage

Tags: signage

Is there a better way to phrase "Parking Around Back" for signage?

Currently the signage at the business says this phrase. However, the
signs are being replaced due to age and wear. I am wondering if there is
a better grammatical way to say this. Customers have to follow a long driveway to get to the parking lot behind the business.

Comment: If you have regular customers that park around back, stay with what you have.  It's fine grammatically, and its less common phrasing makes it stick in people's minds.

Comment: Please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Add a directional multi-segmented arrow. It sounds like the signs would need to be in the portrait orientation.

Answer (score 1):

"Parking in rear" is the traditional way to indicate that the parking lot is behind the building on which it's posted. It may generate some juvenile giggles, though, since "rear" may be read as referring to someone's posterior.